# Content alignment within Bootstrap 4 carousel/ disabling left indicator

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, carousel, vertical-alignment

So what I am trying to do is take the [example-carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/) from bootstraps site, and take the table on slide one and center it vertically within the carousel. I have tried most of their utility classes but nothing I do seems to work:( I would also like to disable the left arrow on slide one and the right arrow on slide 3

HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item">
<img class="first-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="First slide">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<table class="table table-sm text-center">
<thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">First</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Mark</td>
    <table class="table table-sm text-center">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-sm text-center">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
          <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active"> <img class="second-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Second slide">
  <div class="container"> </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item"> <img class="third-slide" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" alt="Third slide">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
      <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Browse gallery</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 32rem;
}
```

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llmff.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have used some external code for bootstrap 4 to hide the arrow. Hope this helps.

```js
$('#demo').on('slid.bs.carousel', '', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  $this.children('.carousel-control').show();

  if ($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:first').hasClass('active')) {
    $this.children('.carousel-control-prev').hide();
  } else if ($('.carousel-inner .carousel-item:last').hasClass('active')) {
    $this.children('.carousel-control-next').hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-wrap="false" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```